# How to collect question's viewcount on SOF?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. I am writing SQL to calculate the questions' view under one tag. For example, to calculate all questions' views under Javascript. I am using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to test if it works.

This is what I wrote:

```
SELECT questions.Id, questions.ViewCount;

FROM Posts questions;

WHERE Tag varchar(250) = ##Tag:string## AND questions.posttypeid = 1;

order by questions.viewcount DESC;
```

But in the WHERE line, there is a mistake: `Line 2: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`

**Update:**

Thanks to @Sergey and @a_horse_with_no_name, I removed ";" and revised my codes like this:

```
SELECT questions.Id, questions.ViewCount

FROM Posts questions

WHERE Tags = ##Tag:string## AND questions.posttypeid = 1

order by questions.viewcount DESC
```

But [the result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1358170) is nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: please remove   ;

Comment: The `;` goes at the very end of the statement, not on every line. And single line comments in SQL are introduced with `--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished it. It can be used on: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

```
SELECT posts.Id, posts.ViewCount

FROM Posts, PostTags, Tags

WHERE Tags.id = PostTags.TagId AND posts.Id = PostTags.PostId
  AND Tags.TagName = ##TagName:string##

order by posts.viewcount DESC
```